# Creating standalone executable from a NetLogo model

Tags: compilation, simulation, executable, netlogo, modeling

I have a NetLogo model. I want to have a standalone executable with the same/similar interface and behavior. I want the user to be able to run my model without downloading/installing NetLogo first. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a programming language or framework to which I can easily translate from my NetLogo model?

Comment: If your model uses no extensions, the best cross-platform solution to your need might be [NetLogo Web](https://netlogoweb.org/).

Comment: @Alan I'll try it.